# MySQL sum of a calculation error

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm struggling with calculating the sum of another calculation in MySQL Workbench. I don't really know how to explain it in words, so I'll provide some data.

Here I have tables and data:

```
drop database if exists GDPR;
create database if not exists GDPR;

use GDPR;

drop table if exists Company;

create table Company 
(
    id_company int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar (50),
    primary key (id_company)
) auto_increment = 1;

drop table if exists GDPR_steps;

create table GDPR_steps 
(
    id_step int not null auto_increment,
    id_company int,
    name varchar (50),
    primary key (id_step),
    foreign key (id_company) references Company (id_company)
) auto_increment = 1;

drop table if exists compliance;

create table compliance  
(
    id_com int not null auto_increment,
    id_step int,
    initiative varchar (50),
    status varchar (10),
    primary key (id_com),
    foreign key (id_step) references gdpr_steps (id_step)
) auto_increment = 1;

insert into company 
values (null, 'Mango'), (null, 'Kiwi');

insert into gdpr_steps 
values (null, 1, 'Awareness'), (null, 1, 'Information you hold'),
       (null, 2, 'Awareness'), (null, 2, 'Information you hold');

insert into compliance 
values (null, 1, 'E-mail all employees',  '1'),
       (null, 1, 'E-mail all applicants', '0'),
       (null, 2, 'Delete some data', '1'),
       (null, 3, 'Call stakeholders', '1'),
       (null, 4, 'Review data', '0');
```

I have this query which calculates the ratio of completion for each step by each company based on the `status` of each of the `initiatives` belonging to a certain step.

```
select 
    company.name as 'Company',
    gdpr_steps.name as 'ID Step',
    (sum(compliance.status)/count(compliance.status)) * 100 as 'Ratio %'
from
    compliance, company, gdpr_steps
where 
    gdpr_steps.id_step = compliance.id_step 
    and company.id_company = gdpr_steps.id_company
group by 
    compliance.id_step, company.id_company;
```

The query above returns this output:

```
Company   ID Step               Ratio %
-----------------------------------------
Mango     Awareness             50
Mango     Information you hold  100
Kiwi      Awareness             100
Kiwi      Information you hold  0
```

Now, when I want to calculate the ratio per company (eg. summing the ratio from step1 with the one from step2 and divide it by 2) I can't make it work. Which would be like

```
Company   Overall ratio %
Mango     (Awareness (50) + Information you hold (100)) / nr of steps (2 in our case)
Kiwi      (Awareness  (0) + Information you hold (100)) / nr of steps (2 in our case)
```

Which in our case would result in something like:

```
Name    Overall ratio %
Mango   75
Kiwi    50
```

I have tried something like

```
select 
    company.name,
    ((sum(compliance.status)/count(compliance.status)) * 100)/ count(gdpr_steps.id_step)
from
    compliance, company, gdpr_steps 
where 
    gdpr_steps.id_step = compliance.id_step 
    and company.id_company = gdpr_steps.id_company
group by 
    company.id_company;
```

This one doesn't seem to work at all, as I receive totally different values than expected.

Could you please explain me what I got wrong?

Kind regards!

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992. Why not comply?

Comment: Also, it's great that you provided some sample data, but can you please test data before posting it.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's how I've learned it in school... and I have like 3-4 classes of MySQL so far. I'm sorry for my writing.

Comment: I have uploaded the question and I've fixed the errors; now it should work fine.

Comment: Go to a other school if they still teaching the old comma join syntax instead of the inner join syntax

Comment: I still need to finish this one... or at least pass this year :D

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're after the following...

```
SELECT company
     , AVG(`ratio %`) n
  FROM
     (
        -- your query here --
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY company;
```

Comment: I have edited my question and now it explains better what I was trying to do. I have also tried your code, but it doesn't return the values I expect to receive. If you are willing to help me a bit more, could you please take a look at the updated question, maybe now is easier to understant what I need.

Comment: Yess! That's the one! Well, thank you so much for the first one you gave me. I have seen the way of writing the queries and I'll try to adapt. One more question that I have: the `n` and `x` you've used, are meant for defining the...? I mean, I know they are mandatory but I don't really understand what they are good for.

Comment: They're aliases - a column alias and a table alias respectively. The column alias is so that it's easy to refer to the result in your application code. The table alias is mandatory, but is also useful for referencing - especially in more complicated queries.